# WordPress: echoing just the first 60characters of the post title

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, ternary-operator

I am styling a WordPress Theme and I would like to make sure that if the post title is longer than 60 characters it shows the first 6ß0 characters + 
three points (...) at the end

In Native Php would like:

```
<?php    
     if (strlen($title) <= 60) {
        echo %title
     }  else {
        echo (substr($title, 60) . "..."
     }                          
?>
```

My problem is that inside WordPress the syntax of variables is not **$title** but **%title** as you could see in the code:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title ' ); ?>
```

**My questions are:**

1. How would be the final IF inside WordPress
2. How would be in shorthand if/else (ternary) form?

Thanks

Comment: you want to truncate title every were except single page?

Comment: No, this is in the post navigation at the bottom of each post. So the next-post and the prev-post titles are not that big. This is just in the mobile phone version @media (max-width: 360px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this by creating your custom post_nav function

```
<div class="prev-posts pull-left">
    <?php
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
    if ($prev_post)
    {
        $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
        if (strlen($prev_title) >= 60)  //<-- here is your custom checking
        {
            $prev_title = (substr($prev_title, 0, 60)) . "...";
        }
        echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title . '" class=" "><strong><<< &quot;' . $prev_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
    }

    ?>
</div>
<div class="next-posts pull-right">
    <?php
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if ($next_post)
    {
        $next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));
        if (strlen($next_title) >= 60) //<-- here is your custom checking
        {
            $next_title = (substr($next_title, 0, 60)) . "...";
        }
        echo "\t" . '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title . '" class=" "><strong>&quot;' . $next_title . '&quot; >>></strong></a>' . "\n";
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!